# Encoding string to UTF-8. Error trying to use EncoderReplacementFallback

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8, .net-4.8

I was trying to convert an string from **ISO-8859-13** and **windows-1253**, to UTF-8, using the enconding methods in C# and Net Framework 4.8.
I copy the code that Im using to try to clarify my issue. This is the code:

```cs
 public class EncodingHelper
    {
        public string Convert(string input, string encoding) 
        {
            var encode = Encoding.GetEncoding(encoding);
            var tmpBytes = encode.GetBytes(input);
            var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(tmpBytes);
            return result;
        }

        public string ConvertWithFallBack(string input, string encoding)
        {
            var encode = Encoding.GetEncoding(encoding, new EncoderReplacementFallback("$"), new DecoderReplacementFallback("*"));
            var tmpBytes = encode.GetBytes(input);
            var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(tmpBytes);
            return result;
        }

        public static void Execute() 
        { 
            var helper = new EncodingHelper();
            var value = "TÕ MOKLH VJÖMG";
            Console.WriteLine($"Current Value: {value}");
            Console.WriteLine($"W-1253 (Convert): {helper.Convert(value, "windows-1253")}");
            Console.WriteLine($"W-1253 (ConvertWithFallBack): {helper.ConvertWithFallBack(value, "windows-1253")}");

            Console.WriteLine($"ISO-8859-13 (Convert): {helper.Convert(value, "ISO-8859-13")}");
            Console.WriteLine($"ISO-8859-13 (ConvertWithFallBack): {helper.ConvertWithFallBack(value, "ISO-8859-13")}");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

But there is a problem with some characters using **ISO-8859-13**, so I decided to using the class "EncoderReplacementFallback" to replace the characters that not found in the encoding.
In the following link, I found the table of conversion:

- https://string-functions.com/encodingtable.aspx?encoding=28603&decoding=65001
- https://string-functions.com/encodingtable.aspx?encoding=1253&decoding=65001

I try to understand why when I use this code: "Encoding.GetEncoding(encoding);" for the encoding **windows-1253** works properly, but if use this code "Encoding.GetEncoding(encoding, new EncoderReplacementFallback("$"), new DecoderReplacementFallback("*"));" this fail.
The same I believe happen with the encoding **ISO-8859-13** because this is not show the correct chars to replace.
This is the response:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wx5XV.png)
Somebody knows why is the reason for that behaviour?
Im expecting that this works for the enconding **windows-1253** in the two methods, but if Im using the EncoderReplacementFallback, it is like this dont know the special chars.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Windows-1253 is for Greek.  What language is your example?  Google Translate couldn't figure it out.

Comment: It looks like you are encoding a Unicode string as Windows-1253 or ISO-8859-13, then decoding those bytes as UTF-8.  That just results in [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).

Comment: Yes, that is an example. This is a name from the Asia zone, maybe there is an issue in the interface that sends the name, with specials chars, but my question was related to the use of EncoderReplacementFallback("$"), If I use the method GetEncoding only defining the encoding name, this works properly (In the case that the windows-1253) but if I use the overloaded method that receives the EncoderReplacementFallback("$"), this began to fail. I don't understand the reason for that.